# listview scrolling using topItem property

Tags: vb.net, listview

I need your help again.

I have a list of films grouped for the first letter of the title
I'm writing a routine that when pressing two keys (PageDown and PageUp) is placed on the first title of the next letter or the previous one.

```
Private Sub frmMovieDatabase_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles lvFilmDetail.KeyDown
    If Not lvFilmDetail.ShowGroups Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ctr_max_groups As Integer = lvFilmDetail.Groups.Count - 1
    Dim ctr_curr_group As Integer = 0

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown Or
        e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp Then

        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.PageDown
                ctr_curr_group = lvFilmDetail.Groups.IndexOf(currentGroup) + 1
                If ctr_curr_group > ctr_max_groups Then
                    ctr_curr_group = 0
                End If
                currentGroup = lvFilmDetail.Groups.Item(ctr_curr_group)

            Case Keys.PageUp
                ctr_curr_group = lvFilmDetail.Groups.IndexOf(currentGroup) - 1
                If ctr_curr_group < 0 Then
                    ctr_curr_group = ctr_max_groups
                End If

                currentGroup = lvFilmDetail.Groups.Item(ctr_curr_group)
        End Select

        MsgBox(currentGroup.Items(0).Text)
        lvFilmDetail.TopItem = currentGroup.Items(0)
        MsgBox(lvFilmDetail.TopItem.Text)

        e.SuppressKeyPress = True

    End If


End Sub
```

The first msgbox correctly displays the first record of each group. The msgbox indicated after the assignment of the item to the topItem property, always returns me the first record of the Listview does not make pagination work

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Marcello

Comment: Marcello, this is your fourth question and you have not accepted a single answer. When an answer leads you to a solution it is customary to thank the poster by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: I'm not used to using the forums and I apologize for not accepting / thanking those who helped me.
In one of the Posts, I have no answers but only comments. I do not know how to close / accept that Post's answers.

Comment: In the case of no answer, you post a comment asking the most helpful commenter to post his comment as an answer and then accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say that that `TopItem` property breaks when using groups.  This code might be acceptable, which at least ensures that the first item of the next group is visible:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode <> Keys.PageUp AndAlso e.KeyCode <> Keys.PageDown Then Return

    Dim groups = ListView1.Groups
    Dim groupCount = groups.Count
    Dim group = ListView1.FocusedItem.Group
    Dim groupIndex = groups.IndexOf(group)

    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.PageUp
            groupIndex -= 1

            If groupIndex < 0 Then
                groupIndex = groupCount - 1
            End If
        Case Keys.PageDown
            groupIndex += 1

            If groupIndex = groupCount Then
                groupIndex = 0
            End If
    End Select

    group = groups(groupIndex)

    Dim item = group.Items(0)

    ListView1.FocusedItem = item
    ListView1.EnsureVisible(item.Index)

    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tryed your code, but I want to position the first record of any group on the Listview's top. Your code show the first record of the next group on the listview's bottom

Comment: It does specifically display it at the bottom but rather simply scrolls the `ListView` as far as required to make the item visible.  If you're scrolling up then that will mean at the top but if you're scrolling down the it will mean at the bottom.  If `TopItem` doesn't work, which I suspect is because it hasn't been designed to work with groups, then this may be the best you can manage.

Comment: It is not what I would like, but at this point I adapt and continue with the rest of the coding. Thanks for your help

Comment: For the record, my previous comment should have started with "It doesn't" rather than "It does".